# Why am I getting this invalid syntax in Dictionary using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Just started Python yesterday (after learning Javascript) and really liking the language. Just ran into this syntax error today and it does not make any sense to me. I have included a space before all the semi-colons when defining the variable and did not work. Wasn't able to find a solution after searching on web either. Any help as to why I am experiencing this error is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Here is my function

```
def weekday_name(day_of_week):
    """Return name of weekday.
    
        >>> weekday_name(1)
        'Sunday'
        
        >>> weekday_name(7)
        'Saturday'
        
    For days not between 1 and 7, return None
    
        >>> weekday_name(9)
        >>> weekday_name(0)
    """
    weekdays = {
        "1": "Sunday"
        "2": "Monday"
        "3": "Tuesday"
        "4": "Wedensday"
        "5": "Thursday"
        "6": "Friday"
        "7": "Saturday"
    }
    return weekdays['day_of_week']
```

Comment: You want commas between those entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
weekdays = {
        "1": "Sunday"
        "2": "Monday"
        "3": "Tuesday"
        "4": "Wedensday"
        "5": "Thursday"
        "6": "Friday"
        "7": "Saturday"
    }
```

Is invalid syntax. You need commas between the entries, as in

```
weekdays = {
        "1": "Sunday",
        "2": "Monday",
        "3": "Tuesday",
        "4": "Wedensday",  # Wednesday?
        "5": "Thursday",
        "6": "Friday",
        "7": "Saturday",
    }
```

As an aside, you've also basically defined a list as a dictionary. OK, the numbers are strings, but why? Consider a list:

```
def weekday_name(day_of_week):
    """Return name of weekday.
    
        >>> weekday_name(1)
        'Sunday'
        
        >>> weekday_name(7)
        'Saturday'
        
    For days not between 1 and 7, return None
    
        >>> weekday_name(9)
        >>> weekday_name(0)
    """
    weekdays = ["Sunday",
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday"]
    return weekdays[(int(day_of_week) - 1) % 7]
```

Comment: Thanks! Should have caught this earlier... along with the misspelling. Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Also, was not able  to get my original function to work. Thank you for the recommendation. Makes much more sense than creating a dictionary